# 13.04 wont start, "cant identify screen, graphics card etc..." error

Tags: installation, 13.04, graphics, mode

Trying to start 13.04 after a recent installation.

A window appears that says "Cannot correctly detect the screen, graphics card, and input device settings" You will need to set these yourself.  Standby as display restarts"  Then there is only a terminal window, which says "* Checking battery state    ...  [ok]"  and it just hangs there and does nothing and does not respond to any input"

any suggestions?

thanks,
stephen

Comment: Additional info:  It did launch and run correctly several times before I installed a program, it is only now after the installation it does this.  But I can't get into the program to fix it!!

Comment: Could you add information such as what model of computer or graphics card you have?

Comment: HP Pavillion tx1308nr: Vista Home Premium, 32bit, SP2, DirectX v10.0. Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150, driver v179.91.

Comment: This seems to be most applicable.  However, I don't see anything in my boot commands that says "quiet splash" or "nomodeset".  I have screen shots of whats in there but I guess I can't copy the text or attach the pics here.

Comment: Please post screenshot, in comment or in question body as link, we'll edit the question to add it properly.

Answer (score 0):

So I reinstalled 13.04 after struggling with modifying the boot commands which didn't seem to accomplish much.  I gave a larger disk space allocation, it started fine.

thank you all for your help

thanks
stephen

Comment: The issue may be that if you update the kernel after installing proprietary graphics drivers, the module does not get carried over. So reinstalling the graphics drivers via command line in Recovery Mode would solve that.

Comment: @Stephen please never post `thanks`, `Stephen`, ir any other irrelevant text in any post anywhere in the Stack Exchange Network -- it adds unnecessary noise/length to a page.

Answer (score -1):

Install the system again or it is better to have 12.04. I think it supports more hardware stuff.
Check this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/index.html

Maybe you will find an answer

Comment: *"Maybe you will find an answer"* <-- Please be more specific or just don't answer a question; it's not useful to just post general links without actually answering the question here.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't see much there applied to my condition